# Bulk Excel Upload from Angular shows Page Unresponsive

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs-directive, node-modules

I am trying to upload the excel from UI (angular8 and node 14) and try to process it, but while retrieving data from excel for bulk data(1800 rows almost 12mb file ) it shows a Page Unresponsive pop-up many times and I can understand, chrome browser trying to use a lot of memory and result is Page Unresponsive pop-up. is there any way to disable or not show this pop-up or any solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

I am attaching below working Ts file code.

[image]

code:

```
onFileChange(evt: any) {
  const target: DataTransfer = (evt.target) as DataTransfer;
  const selectedFile = evt.target.files[0];
  const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
  reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  const bstr: string = e.target.result;
  const wbk: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
  
    wbk.SheetNames.forEach(sheet =>{
      setTimeout(()=>{}, 250);  //I am trying to use timeout to refresh the flow but not working 
     const  data1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wbk.Sheets[sheet]);    
     console.log(data1);
    })

  }
};
```